# Debian: How to set an empty password for user "sync"?

Tags: passwords, debian, user-accounts, pam

The Debian documentation at https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups says:

> sync: The shell of user sync is /bin/sync. Thus, if its password is
>   set to something easy to guess (such as ""), anyone can sync the
>   system at the console even if they have don't have an account.

I want to follow that advice. But it is not easy to allow an empty-password login for a particular user.

I guess I would have to re-configure PAM somehow to allow this.

What is the least intrusive way to do this?

I do not want to allow empty passwords for all users, just for this particular user.

I also would prefer to add an additional "plug-in" configuration files to /etc/pam.d/ rather than modifying an existing file there (which might create trouble for future updates).

Is this possible? And if, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is probably to directly edit your password-file:

```
# vipw -s
```

(this will open the `shadow` file (`-s`) with the "password editor" (`vipw`).

1. locate the "sync" entry (it will look like `sync:*:12345:0:99999:7:::`
2. the second entry (`*`) in the line is the actual password (`*` being an illegal password, so the account is actually locked; if you have set a real password, you will see some hash value)
3. remove the password, so you get something like `sync::12345:0:99999:7:::`
   (so there is nothing between the 1st and the 2nd `:` colon); keep the rest of the line intact)
4. save the file and exit the editor

now you are done. test by logging in as user `sync`.

```
# login -f sync
```

otoh, I'm not really sure whether this is really what you want (as it requires physicial access to the computer to login as the `sync` user. `ssh` will prohibit empty passwords,...)

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked! I was using sudoedit to edit /etc/shadow safely, and was astonished to see that emptying the password hash field really did the job. I had rather assumed an empty password hash would allow no login whatsoever. But it did! And yes, your solution is exactly what I wanted. Only people with physical access shall be able to sync, shutdown or reboot the box. (I will now add more password-less pseudo-accounts for the latter two.) I need these because I use XDM which has no buttons for this. And it also works without X11 running, too.